Named router position & route definition
I have a main router-outlet placed within app component.
Also, I have named router-outlet placed within one of the components that are rendered when one of the routes defined at the root level are hit.
Question is, where should my routes for named router be defined: at root level or as children of the route for the component where my named router-outlet is?
I assumed it should be defined at children level but that way it doesn't work: routes show in browser url correctly but component is not rendered.
On the other hand, when I put route definition at root level, all works as expected.
Why?

I clear your dought here...
1) Root level Router
If you place router-outlet in root level that means your angular application can be global level routing you can access any page with that routing name.
2) Child Level Router
If you place children specific routing component that means you can access only that child page with routing name
in simple word
Imagine you're in a shopping mall, and there's a big directory at the entrance showing all the sections available in the mall. Each section has its own map showing the stores inside it.
Defined at the Root Level: If the directory at the entrance lists all the sections in the mall, such as "Clothing", "Electronics", "Food Court", and "Entertainment", this is like defining routes at the root level. No matter where you are in the mall, you can always find your way to these main sections.
Defined as Children of a Route: Now, let's say you're inside the "Clothing" section of the mall. Within the "Clothing" section, there's a smaller directory showing different aisles like "Men's Wear", "Women's Wear", and "Children's Wear". This is like defining routes as children of a route. These routes are specific to the "Clothing" section and can only be accessed from within it.
So, if you're at the entrance (root level) and want to go to the "Clothing" section, you'll find it on the main directory. Once inside the "Clothing" section, you can navigate to its specific aisles (children routes) using the smaller directory within that section.
